# Can I use hook form alter to add an attribute to a webform field?

Tags: forms

I am trying to use hook form alter to add an onchange attribute to a select field but it is not working. Is it possible or is there something wrong with my module code?

```
function addonchange_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  // target a single form
  if($form_id == "webform_client_form_22"){
    $form['submitted']['company']['#onchange'] = 'changevalue';
  }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to do something like this:

```
function addonchange_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  // target a single form
  if($form_id == "webform_client_form_22"){
    $form['submitted']['company']['#attributes']['onchange'] = 'changevalue';
  }
}
```